# What's the difference between "Chinese social media marketing" and "Social media marketing in China"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity, social-media

> 1. **Chinese social media marketing advice from local experts**. Avoid common mistakes and dominate in Chinese social media.
> 2. **Powerful advice on social media marketing in China from local experts**. Follow these tips for business leaders and get ahead in China.

What's the difference between "Chinese social media marketing" and "Social media marketing in China"? I think they're the same thing but they're listed as two points.

Comment: Ms Huang, the person voting to close your question probably wants you to explain *where* they're listed as "two points", along with some more context.

Comment: The phrase *Chinese social media marketing*, considered on its own, is syntactically ambiguous between Chinese-social-media marketing and Chinese social-media-marketing, but that is probably too obvious to be worthy of posting as an answer.

Comment: If someone is wondering why they cannot post an answer unless they have 10 reputation, it's because the protected question attracted two spam answers within hours of each other.

Answer (score 3):

There's an entire career path in international diplomacy dealing with the vexedness of most nations' "One China" policies but,

- for almost all intents and purposes, **China** is essentially the People's Republic of China or its government.
- In marketing or int'l travel, it'll usually be explicitly Mainland China plus Hainan.

The adjective **Chinese**, on the other hand, can mean a ton of separate things:

- of or related to Mainland China (大陆);
- of or related to its government (中华人民共和國政府);
- of or related to Greater China (中國), inclusive of the SARs and Taiwan;
- of or related to the citizens of China (中國人), inclusive of Uyghurs, Tibetans, &c.;
- of or related to the Han Chinese (汉族人) specifically;
- of or related to the written Chinese language (中文), intelligible in various dialects;
- of or related to Mandarin Chinese (普通話) specifically.

In B2B contexts, you're also going to see a distinction between foreign companies operating in the Chinese market (whatever the boundaries of that are) versus the local Chinese companies.

In your two bullet points, you're right that it's badly expressed marketing jargon. Taken most charitably, "Chinese social media marketing advice" is advice on marketing on PRC (and Chinese-language) social media platforms like Weibo, Weixin, and Bilibili and "advice on social media marketing in China" is advice on adjusting general social media marketing to deal with PRC consumers and regulators. There's not a lot of daylight between those two categories, but there's some.

That's not really what the glosses suggest they mean, though. The actual people you're dealing with are using the first category to describe "common mistakes in the Chinese social media market" and the second to describe "tips for business leaders to get ahead in the Chinese social media market". That's not at all what the headers are actually talking about. It's just badly done.

Answer (score 0):

> "Chinese social media marketing"

(i) The way that Chinese people (regardless of where they are in the world) market social media.

(ii) The Chinese style of marketing social media.

> "Social media marketing in China"

The way anyone markets social media within China<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> You should understand "China" from either the context, or subjectively.

Comment: This assumes that *social media marketing* refers to marketing (i.e. getting people to use) social media; it can, however, also refer to marketing various goods and services through these media.

Comment: @jsw29 I agree with both you and Greybeard. It's a little like the difference between "French salad dressing" which could be applied to salads anywhere but consists of oil, vinegar, salt herbs and, usually, mustard; and "Salad dressing in France" which refers to dressings applied to salads in France. This will include "french dressing" but could also refer to mayonnaise or even, god forbid, British salad cream.